# How to intercept an async method with IAsyncEnumerable<T> as return type in .netcore 3.0

Tags: c#, .net-core, c#-8.0

Im trying to implement an proxy that takes the work of logging method calls. With awareness of async methods that should be called and some of the logs should only be made after the method finished but the proxy method should not be a blockig call.

After many tries this is the solution I came up with.

```
namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Reflection;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    public static class ObjectExtender
    {
        internal static bool IsOfGenericType(this object obj, Type check, out Type? genericType)
        {
            Type actType = obj.GetType();
            while (actType != null && actType != typeof(object))
            {
                if (actType.IsGenericType && actType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == check.GetGenericTypeDefinition())
                {
                    genericType = actType;
                    return true;
                }

                actType = actType.BaseType;
            }

            genericType = null;
            return false;
        }
    }

    public class Class1<T> : DispatchProxy
    {
        private static readonly MethodInfo AsyncEnumeration;
        private static readonly Dictionary<Type, MethodInfo> CachedAsyncEnumerationMethodInfos = new Dictionary<Type, MethodInfo>();
        private static readonly Dictionary<Type, MethodInfo> CachedGenericTaskMethodInfos = new Dictionary<Type, MethodInfo>();
        private static readonly Dictionary<Type, MethodInfo> CachedSyncEnumerationMethodInfos = new Dictionary<Type, MethodInfo>();
        private static readonly MethodInfo GenericTask;
        private static readonly MethodInfo SyncEnumeration;
        private T _decorated = default!;

        static Class1()
        {
            GenericTask = typeof(Class1<T>).GetMethod("HandleTaskGenericAsync", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
            AsyncEnumeration = typeof(Class1<T>).GetMethod("Wrapper", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic           | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
            SyncEnumeration = typeof(Class1<T>).GetMethod("SyncWrapper", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic        | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
        }

        public static T Create(T decorated)
        {
            T proxy = Create<T, Class1<T>>();
            Class1<T> ap = proxy as Class1<T> ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(decorated));
            ap._decorated = decorated;

            return proxy;
        }

        private static Task<T2> HandleTaskGenericAsync<T1, T2>(T1 result, MethodInfo methodName) where T1 : Task<T2>
        {
            return result.ContinueWith(parent =>
                                       {
                                           Console.WriteLine($"After: {methodName}");
                                           return parent.Result;
                                       });
        }

        protected override object Invoke(MethodInfo targetMethod, object[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Before: {targetMethod}");

                object result = targetMethod.Invoke(_decorated, args);

                if (result is Task resultTask)
                {
                    if (!resultTask.IsOfGenericType(typeof(Task<>), out Type? genericType))
                    {
                        return resultTask.ContinueWith(task =>
                                                       {
                                                           if (task.Exception != null)
                                                           {
                                                               Console.WriteLine($"{task.Exception.InnerException ?? task.Exception}, {targetMethod}");
                                                           }
                                                           else
                                                           {
                                                               Console.WriteLine($"After: {targetMethod}");
                                                           }
                                                       });
                    }

                    Debug.Assert(genericType != null, nameof(genericType) + " != null");
                    Type resultType = genericType.GetGenericArguments()[0]; // Task<> hat nur einen.
                    if (!CachedGenericTaskMethodInfos.ContainsKey(resultType))
                    {
                        CachedGenericTaskMethodInfos.Add(resultType, GenericTask.MakeGenericMethod(genericType, resultType));
                    }

                    return CachedGenericTaskMethodInfos[resultType].Invoke(null, new object[] {resultTask, targetMethod});
                }

                Type returnType = targetMethod.ReturnType;
                if (returnType.IsGenericType && returnType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IAsyncEnumerable<>))
                {
                    Type resultType = returnType.GetGenericArguments()[0]; //IAsyncEnumerable hat nur eines
                    if (!CachedAsyncEnumerationMethodInfos.ContainsKey(resultType))
                    {
                        CachedAsyncEnumerationMethodInfos.Add(resultType, AsyncEnumeration.MakeGenericMethod(resultType));
                    }

                    return CachedAsyncEnumerationMethodInfos[resultType].Invoke(null, new[] {result, targetMethod});
                }

                if (returnType.IsGenericType && returnType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>))
                {
                    Type resultType = returnType.GetGenericArguments()[0]; //IAsyncEnumerable hat nur eines
                    if (!CachedSyncEnumerationMethodInfos.ContainsKey(resultType))
                    {
                        CachedSyncEnumerationMethodInfos.Add(resultType, SyncEnumeration.MakeGenericMethod(resultType));
                    }

                    return CachedSyncEnumerationMethodInfos[resultType].Invoke(null, new[] {result, targetMethod});
                }

                Console.WriteLine($"After: {targetMethod}");

                return result;
            }
            catch (TargetInvocationException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{ex.InnerException ?? ex}, {targetMethod}");
                throw;
            }
        }

        private static IEnumerable<T> SyncWrapper<T>(IEnumerable<T> inner, MethodInfo targetMethod)
        {
            foreach (T t in inner)
            {
                yield return t;
            }

            Console.WriteLine($"After List: {targetMethod}");
        }

        private static async IAsyncEnumerable<T> Wrapper<T>(IAsyncEnumerable<T> inner, MethodInfo targetMethod)
        {
            await foreach (T t in inner)
            {
                yield return t;
            }

            Console.WriteLine($"After List: {targetMethod}");
        }
    }
}
```

This proxy intercepts method calls just the way I wanted to.
This is the output of my Test

```
---Test sync calls---
Before: Void Run()
Inside: Run()
After: Void Run()
Before: System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Int32] RunEnumerator[Int32](Int32[])
Inside Start: RunEnumerator()
Erg: 1
Erg: 2
Erg: 3
Erg: 4
Inside Ende: RunEnumerator()
After List: System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Int32] RunEnumerator[Int32](Int32[])
---Test async calls---
Before: System.Threading.Tasks.Task RunAsync()
Inside: RunAsync()
After: System.Threading.Tasks.Task RunAsync()
Before: System.Threading.Tasks.Task RunAwaitAsync()
Inside: RunAwaitAsync()
After: System.Threading.Tasks.Task RunAwaitAsync()
Before: System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.String] RunAwaitGenericTask[String](System.String)
Inside: RunAwaitGenericTask()
After: System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.String] RunAwaitGenericTask[String](System.String)
Before: System.Collections.Generic.IAsyncEnumerable`1[System.Int32] RunAwaitGenericEnumeratorTask[Int32](Int32[])
Inside Start: RunAwaitGenericEnumeratorTask()
Erg: 1
Erg: 2
Erg: 3
Erg: 4
Inside Ende: RunAwaitGenericEnumeratorTask()
After List: System.Collections.Generic.IAsyncEnumerable`1[System.Int32] RunAwaitGenericEnumeratorTask[Int32](Int32[])
```

Comment: You'll have to actually wrap the `IAsyncEnumerable` (and the resulting `IAsyncEnumerator`) with your own implementations so you can invoke the logging when the enumeration starts/ends. You can simply ignore cancellation (I think) as the wrapped enumerator will take care of it. That is, `async IAsyncEnumerable<T> Wrapper<T>(IAsyncEnumerable<T> inner) { await Task.Yield(); /* your prologue code */ await foreach (var t in inner) { yield return t; } /* your epilogue code */ }`, `MakeGenericMethod`, invoke.

Comment: Please clarify your question, its unclear what you need to "figure out"

Comment: You may also want to investigate aspect-oriented programming: https://www.dotnetcurry.com/patterns-practices/1305/aspect-oriented-programming-aop-csharp-using-solid

Comment: I editet the initial post to reflect the current status.
`typed.OnCompleted(o => Console.WriteLine($"After List: {targetMethod), null, 0, ValueTaskSourceOnCompletedFlags.None);`
is the closest I came to a solution. However this does not work as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution. Thankt to Jeroen Mostert for pointing me in the right direction.

```
namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Reflection;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    public static class ObjectExtender
    {
        internal static bool IsOfGenericType(this object obj, Type check, out Type? genericType)
        {
            Type actType = obj.GetType();
            while (actType != null && actType != typeof(object))
            {
                if (actType.IsGenericType && actType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == check.GetGenericTypeDefinition())
                {
                    genericType = actType;
                    return true;
                }

                actType = actType.BaseType;
            }

            genericType = null;
            return false;
        }
    }

    public class Class1<T> : DispatchProxy
    {
        private static readonly MethodInfo AsyncEnumeration;
        private static readonly Dictionary<Type, MethodInfo> CachedAsyncEnumerationMethodInfos = new Dictionary<Type, MethodInfo>();
        private static readonly Dictionary<Type, MethodInfo> CachedGenericTaskMethodInfos = new Dictionary<Type, MethodInfo>();
        private static readonly Dictionary<Type, MethodInfo> CachedSyncEnumerationMethodInfos = new Dictionary<Type, MethodInfo>();
        private static readonly MethodInfo GenericTask;
        private static readonly MethodInfo SyncEnumeration;
        private T _decorated = default!;

        static Class1()
        {
            GenericTask = typeof(Class1<T>).GetMethod("HandleTaskGenericAsync", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
            AsyncEnumeration = typeof(Class1<T>).GetMethod("Wrapper", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic           | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
            SyncEnumeration = typeof(Class1<T>).GetMethod("SyncWrapper", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic        | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
        }

        public static T Create(T decorated)
        {
            T proxy = Create<T, Class1<T>>();
            Class1<T> ap = proxy as Class1<T> ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(decorated));
            ap._decorated = decorated;

            return proxy;
        }

        private static Task<T2> HandleTaskGenericAsync<T1, T2>(T1 result, MethodInfo methodName) where T1 : Task<T2>
        {
            return result.ContinueWith(parent =>
                                       {
                                           Console.WriteLine($"After: {methodName}");
                                           return parent.Result;
                                       });
        }

        protected override object Invoke(MethodInfo targetMethod, object[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Before: {targetMethod}");

                object result = targetMethod.Invoke(_decorated, args);

                if (result is Task resultTask)
                {
                    if (!resultTask.IsOfGenericType(typeof(Task<>), out Type? genericType))
                    {
                        return resultTask.ContinueWith(task =>
                                                       {
                                                           if (task.Exception != null)
                                                           {
                                                               Console.WriteLine($"{task.Exception.InnerException ?? task.Exception}, {targetMethod}");
                                                           }
                                                           else
                                                           {
                                                               Console.WriteLine($"After: {targetMethod}");
                                                           }
                                                       });
                    }

                    Debug.Assert(genericType != null, nameof(genericType) + " != null");
                    Type resultType = genericType.GetGenericArguments()[0]; // Task<> hat nur einen.
                    if (!CachedGenericTaskMethodInfos.ContainsKey(resultType))
                    {
                        CachedGenericTaskMethodInfos.Add(resultType, GenericTask.MakeGenericMethod(genericType, resultType));
                    }

                    return CachedGenericTaskMethodInfos[resultType].Invoke(null, new object[] {resultTask, targetMethod});
                }

                Type returnType = targetMethod.ReturnType;
                if (returnType.IsGenericType && returnType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IAsyncEnumerable<>))
                {
                    Type resultType = returnType.GetGenericArguments()[0]; //IAsyncEnumerable hat nur eines
                    if (!CachedAsyncEnumerationMethodInfos.ContainsKey(resultType))
                    {
                        CachedAsyncEnumerationMethodInfos.Add(resultType, AsyncEnumeration.MakeGenericMethod(resultType));
                    }

                    return CachedAsyncEnumerationMethodInfos[resultType].Invoke(null, new[] {result, targetMethod});
                }

                if (returnType.IsGenericType && returnType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>))
                {
                    Type resultType = returnType.GetGenericArguments()[0]; //IAsyncEnumerable hat nur eines
                    if (!CachedSyncEnumerationMethodInfos.ContainsKey(resultType))
                    {
                        CachedSyncEnumerationMethodInfos.Add(resultType, SyncEnumeration.MakeGenericMethod(resultType));
                    }

                    return CachedSyncEnumerationMethodInfos[resultType].Invoke(null, new[] {result, targetMethod});
                }

                Console.WriteLine($"After: {targetMethod}");

                return result;
            }
            catch (TargetInvocationException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{ex.InnerException ?? ex}, {targetMethod}");
                throw;
            }
        }

        private static IEnumerable<T> SyncWrapper<T>(IEnumerable<T> inner, MethodInfo targetMethod)
        {
            foreach (T t in inner)
            {
                yield return t;
            }

            Console.WriteLine($"After List: {targetMethod}");
        }

        private static async IAsyncEnumerable<T> Wrapper<T>(IAsyncEnumerable<T> inner, MethodInfo targetMethod)
        {
            await foreach (T t in inner)
            {
                yield return t;
            }

            Console.WriteLine($"After List: {targetMethod}");
        }
    }
}
```